# Add dynamic label on d3 dynamic pie chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, label, pie-chart

I use D3.js to create a dynamic pie chart. I want the user can chose what informations he wants to display. So I want labels can appears an disappears.
(for the moment it's random choice but in future the user can chose particular part of the  pie)

I want to display "age" value on the pie (show this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u9GBq/27/)).

If I tried to append text or create "g" group it doesn't works, the pie chart doesn't stay dynamics ...
I think I must use `var g = svg.selectAll("path").enter().append("g")` somewhere to create group and add text label and path in, but I fail to understand how to do that.

Sorry for my poor english

Thanks for your help

Comment: You can add labels in the same way as the segments, using `text` instead of `path` elements. [Here](http://bl.ocks.org/enjalot/1203641) is an example of a chart with labels.

Comment: Thanks, but in your example there is a "g" group with path and text fort each part, it's what i try to do, but when i try do that, the pie doesn't stay dynamic. I fail to show hide part of the pie whan I add "g" group and text, How can i do that ?

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/MX7JC/9/) is another example that is probably closer to what you want.

Comment: it's look like what i want to do, Iknew this pie chart but when i try to do the same thing it doesn't work (show this Js Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u9GBq/28/)

Answer (score 0):

You weren't adding the `text` element back into the chart on change. I've fixed this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/u9GBq/29/).